# .htaccess file unable to redirect page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

first thing first, this is the first time that I work with .htaccess files, so please be patient and very explanatory.

OK, this is my issue:
I have changed my domain from `www.mydomain.net` to `www.mydomain.co.uk`.

I have a web app installed on various devices, and in the app there is a broken link, broken because of the domain change.
If I press a button in the app, this is the behave of the link:

> `1) www.mydomain.net/registration?update` -> `2)www.mydomain.net/registration/update-details/`

When I press the link, the first one is immediately redirect to the second one, that it is not correct anyway.

I tried using some .htaccess on-line generator, but the didn't work, or (more probable) I did something wrong...

Long story short, I need to be able to redirect the links in this order:

1) www.mydomain.net/registration?update

2) www.mydomain.net/registration/update-details/

3) www.mydomain.co.uk/registration/update-details/

4) www.mydomain.co.uk/update-details/

My .htaccess file is the following:

```
# BEGIN W3TC CDN
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC CDN
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule    ^mydomain\.net/registration$    mydomain.co.uk/update-details  [r]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# DENY ACCESS TO CERTAIN FILES
<Files "README.md">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN W3TC CDN
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END W3TC CDN
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^registration/?$ http://mydomain.co.uk/update-details [L,NC,R=302]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>   
# END WordPress

# DENY ACCESS TO CERTAIN FILES
<Files "README.md">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Better to test it in a new browser to avoid old 301 browser caching issues.